# Socket.io connect doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, server, client

Okey so this is not my whole code, but I think this is the part that you need for this question. So my problem is, I cant connect to my server, everytime the socket.connected returns false. So could you guys help me out?

client side :

```
var host                   = "localhost";
var socketio               = "http://" + host + ":3000";

var io = require('socket.io-client'),
socket = io.connect(socketio);
console.log('check 1' + " " + socket.connected);
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('Connected through sockets.');
});
socket.on('connect_failed', function(){
    console.log('Connection Failed');
});
```

server side :

```
var http = require('http');

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        console.log('createServer');
});
app.listen(3000);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log("go");
});
```

Comment: are you able to fix this? I am getting false status